# How to validate bitwise flags when posted as Integer to the server? Integer can hold various flags combined

Tags: php, bitwise-operators

How would you test if ANY integer value posted is part of the flags you have defined? (A valid combination of those.)

Example:

```
define('IS_NEW', 0);
define('IS_PAID', 2);
define('IS_EXTEND', 4);
define('IS_TRACK', 8);
define('IS_VIP', 16);
define('IS_HOT', 32);
define('IS_BLOCKED', 64);
```

Now the integer posted could be `48`, `50`, `75`, ...

How to verify that the integer consists of our bitwise flag system - in their various combinations - and NOT other values.

`48` is valid, because flags 16 + 32 = 48.

`50` is valid, because flags 2 + 16 + 32 = 48.

`75` is NOT valid, because flags 64 + 8 + 4 = 76.

We want to make sure that no other flag value is included.

Comment: The question is tagged with "bitwise operators", are you having problems using them? F.ex `if ($myInt & IS_NEW) {` means bit 0 was set, `if ($myInt & IS_HOT) {` bit 5, etc.
Note the single `&` which is bitwise AND, as opposed to `&&` for boolean AND.
If you want to test for combinations that would be up to your "if() tree", and perhaps what combos you epxect.

Comment: This is absolutely clear. But how can I identify that the integer given (the sum of potential flags) consists of the predefined flags.

Comment: So you want to check if the integer consists of *nothing but* - combos of - flag values? If you define your "flag series" like that, in an ordered way, you could perhaps check if myInt is outside the range of the sum of all your flags? Or some kind of fallback else clause in your "if lines checking for flags" tree?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Not any other integer that is not part of the defined flags.

Comment: You could also OR your flags together to create a bitmask, and then something like `if ($myInt & BITMASK !== $myInt) {`.

Comment: Does it make sense?

Comment: If you want to handle it strictly programmatically I guess you could use [get_defined_constants()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php) provided you can name your defines in some logical easy to access way.

Comment: Any integer < 128 is a valid combination. FYI, `IS_NEW` must be 1 (2**0)

Comment: Exactly. (Provided that is the actual use case) If all bits from 0 up to some limit are used then it's trivial to construct the largest int possible with those bits and check whether the integer is within that interval. (0 - MAX_POSSIBLE)

Comment: "Any integer < 128 is a valid combination" ... I doubt that you can create `3` out of the defined integers above.

Comment: This is because `IS_NEW` is set to 0: how can you combine it with other flags? BTW, with the above constants: `if ($num < 0 || $num > 127 || $num&1) { *NOT VALID* } else { *VALID* }`

Comment: ⚠️ Which "smart user" closed the question as duplicate? ... The linked question is NOT a duplicate. @whoever: READ the question!

Answer (score 1):

How can you identify that the integer given (the sum of potential flags) consists of the predefined flags...?
Maybe that way:

```
<?php
define('IS_NEW', 0);
define('IS_PAID', 2);
define('IS_EXTEND', 4);
define('IS_TRACK', 8);
define('IS_VIP', 16);
define('IS_HOT', 32);
define('IS_BLOCKED', 64);

class myConsts {
    public $constants = ['IS_NEW','IS_PAID', 'IS_EXTEND', 'IS_TRACK', 'IS_VIP', 'IS_HOT', 'IS_BLOCKED'];

    function __construct() {
        foreach ($this->constants as &$cons) {
            $cons = -constant($cons) -1;  // negation, f.e. 0b...00000001 ==> 0b...11111110 (32 or 64 bits depends of platform)
            //printf("0b%08b.\n", $cons); // (test)
        }
    }
  
    function checkInt($myInt = 0) {   
        foreach ($this->constants as $cons) {
            $myInt = $myInt & $cons;
        }       
        return $myInt;
    }
}

$checkInts = new myConsts();

foreach ([48, 50, 75, 256*200+156] as $getInt) {
    $result = $checkInts->checkInt($getInt);
    if ($result) {
        echo "Int ".sprintf("%u (0b%1$08b)", $getInt)." constains more flags: ", sprintf("0b%08b.", $result), PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "Int ".sprintf("%u (0b%1$08b)", $getInt)." consists only of predefined flags!", PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>
```

Result:

```
Int 48 (0b00110000) consists only of predefined flags!
Int 50 (0b00110010) consists only of predefined flags!
Int 75 (0b01001011) constains more flags: 0b00000001.
Int 51356 (0b1100100010011100) constains more flags: 0b1100100010000000.
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Thank you, that's what was needed. I thought it would be easier. :)